# JMeter ignore Duration time when using Scheduler

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I tried to run Thread group with below details:

- Number of thread: 1
- Ramp-up period: 1
- Loop count: 1

Scheduler box: checked

- Duration:1800
- Start up delay : 1

The thread group is for Login transaction and has 57 samples. 
When I hit Run, the entire thread doesn't run for 1800 sec but for **84 sec**

Is there anything I need to check or configure before run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `Duration` you need to check Loop count as `Forever` in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group)

It may seems off, but it will stop executing right after it reach duration time

> By default, the thread group is configured to loop once through its elements.

Comment: That means, if Duration is set for 1800 sec and it takes 84 sec per user login transaction then total number of thread injected is 1800/84 = 21.42 ~ 21, right?

Comment: @NewToGroovy If loop count number is entered (as 1) it stop when finished, is it's set forever it will stop when Duration is over

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.