# Scheduler execution gets over/stopped before specified time

Tags: jmeter

We are running `Jmeter` scripts in `Scheduler` mode for 1 hour (Master - 4 Slave machines), however the execution gets over/stopped before 1 hour time (ex: it stops in 40 mints).

Below is the setup: Jmeter version 5.1

`Thread Group`: `Scheduler` checked with `Duration` 1 hour, `Forever` is selected.

`CSV config`: `Recycle EOF is set to True`, `Stop thread on EOF is set to False`. The CSV is having 20 rows and these rows data has been used/fetched multiple times during 40 mints.

--`HTTP Sampler`

Tried multiple times with different duration, still the same issue. No errors logged in `jmeter.log` file.

Referred below resource as well:

[JMeter ignore Duration time when using Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52496657/jmeter-ignore-duration-time-when-using-scheduler)

Please suggest to make it to work for complete specified duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately we're not telepathic enough to guess what's wrong without seeing *jmeter.log* file from the master machine and *jmeter-server.log* files from the slaves, the answer should be either in these or in the .jtl results file.

Your test configuration looks very good, just check 3 points:

- make sure that the OS time is synchronised on all the slaves and the master
- Copy your CSV file to all the slaves
- None of `Stop Thread`/`Stop Test`/`Stop Test Now` radiobuttons in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) are checked

  [image]

Also be informed that according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) (or whatever is the latest stable JMeter version available at [JMeter Downloads page](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)) on next available opportunity as it might be the case you're suffering from a form of a bug which has been already fixed.